# MSEchangeReok Error on Exchange Server

Tags: windows, exchange

Got an error appearing on a clients server, the error is as follows.

```
The Microsoft Exchange Replication service failed to start the TCP listener. Error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Replay.TcpListener.StartListening()
```

I have done basic troubleshooting such as restart server, the service etc. I have checked and the database is mounted and both copies are running. This does not seem to be impacting the users in any way.

[image]

As you can see, one of the common reasons people say is that there is something else on the ports that MSE runs on. However it seems that there is nothing else.

In the event log there is nothing but this error logged every 30 seconds, obviously making diagnostics difficult.

Checked and done everything on this;
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b27a4d85-a64b-4f12-ad5a-1e04787807f8/event-viewer-error-socketexception?forum=exchange2010

&
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27411128/Exchange-2010-errors.html

Any help or ideas would be amazing right now.

Thanks

Edit.

Version of Exchange: Exchange Server 2010 V:14.03.0224.002
OS: Server 2008 R2 SP1
Installed programs:
[image]

Single server.

Comment: Is the `Net.Tcp Port Sharing` service installed and running?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, the service is installed and running on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Missing all of the basic information. 
Exact version of Exchange being used, single server or multiple, any third party software on the server at all etc.

Comment: I have updated the post with those details.

Comment: That build is rollup 8, so you well out of date. I would suggest an update to the latest rollup. 
For the Sophos AV, ensure that it has the correct exclusions as per
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332342(v=exchg.141).aspx